# Хранение HTML-кода

Tags: xml, html

Есть ли способ хранить HTML-код в XML(или похожем формате, но не в БД) без экранирования символов '<','>'?

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем. Можете описать суть проблемы? Навскидку скажу, что в XML экранирование обязательно, а HTML файлы в большинстве случаев можно хранить в формате ".html":)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CDATA](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA)

Comment: +1, но всё же придётся экранировать `]]>`.